# Returning ESTA line at IAH?

Tags: air-travel, texas, iah

Could anyone inform me if there is a returning ESTA line in IAH? I am flying there from The Netherlands and have found mostly comments about the airport claiming it is 'the slowest airport ever' and that passport checks and customs usually take over 2 hours.

Is there a returning ESTA line to make things go faster? Is there anything anyone can do to make things go faster?

To clarify, I applied for my ESTA December 2014, and will be travelling to the US for the second time in October 2016.

Comment: Immigration at IAH used to be very slow, but it's had an extreme makeover in the past couple of years.

Comment: Still mostly bad comments from earlier in 2016 but I hope it has improved, thanks for the addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CBP has a [list of airports with APC kiosks](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/automated-passport-control-apc).

> Houston George Bush Intercontinental Airport (IAH)

Note that they are not necessarily at all terminals though.

[Official airport information](http://www.fly2houston.com/iah/international-travel/).

> U.S. or Canadian citizens, U.S. green card holders, legal permanent
>   residents, ESTA and visa-waiver holders may use one of the 50
>   self-service kiosks when arriving at IAH on international flights. All
>   eligible foreign visitors must have entered the U.S. at least once
>   prior.

Comment: That is exactly the information I was looking for, great!